# pulling specific record(s) that match only a set of values across multiple rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to find all of the conversations that have only a set of exact recipients. My tables look like this:

```
Conversation
---------------
id | some other fields

User
---------------
id | some other fields

Recipients
--------------
id | conversation_id | user_id | some other fields
1  | 1               | 1
2  | 1               | 2        
3  | 2               | 1
4  | 2               | 2                
5  | 2               | 3
6  | 3               | 1
7  | 3               | 3
```

Using the above I want to get conversation_id 1 and the only thing I know is the user_id's [1,2] but I dont want any of the other records how would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group on `conversation_id` and then use `having` to filter out the right conversations.  In the query below, the first line demands that both `user_id` 1 and 2 are present.  The second line demands that it does not contain any other `user_id`:

```
select  conversation_id
from    recipients
group by
        conversation_id
having  count(distinct case when user_id in (1,2) then user_id end) = 2
        and count(case when user_id not in (1,2) then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: I've just noticed - shouldn't this be `from recipients`, not `conversation`?

Comment: Dennis has pointed out a fault with my answer - to correct it would essentially turn it into this answer, so I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
 SELECT id
 , conversation_id 
 , user_id
 , ... other columsn
 FROM Recipients 
 WHERE converstaion_id = 1
 AND user_id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: I dont know the conversation_id, but the conversation_id expect from the results is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.* from Conversation c 
  where (select count(distinct user_id) from Recipients 
     where conversation_id=c.id and user_id in (<USER-IDS>))=<NUMBER-OF-USERS>
```

where < USER-IDS > is the comma-separated user ids and < NUMBER-OF-USERS > is the exact number of those users, e.g. 2 in your example.

Comment: This would match a conversation between users 1,2 and 3.  The `where` clause would filter Mr. 3 out, and the subquery would return 2.

Comment: this is returning conversation 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

first find wich conversation_id have user_id that are not in your list (inner sub query)then find conversation_id that is not in this list

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversation_id
FROM         dbo.Recipients
WHERE     (conversation_id NOT IN
                          (SELECT     Recipients_1.conversation_id
                            FROM          dbo.Recipients AS Recipients_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                       (SELECT id AS user_id
                                                         FROM          User
                                                         WHERE      (id IN (1, 2))) AS tbl_user ON tbl_user.user_id = Recipients_1.user_id
                            WHERE      (tbl_user.user_id IS NULL)))
```

Comment: This would exclude conversations between other people, but it does not demand that both Mr. 1 and Mr. 2 are present.  Btw, there's no need to join to `user` for `user_id`.