# Select rows with dynamic search condition on one column

Tags: sql, search, select, dynamic

I have two tables 'SLURRY' and 'MATERIAL' as shown below.

============================================================================
[SLURRY]

```
SLURRY_ID
-----------
3069929
```

[MATERIAL]

```
SLURRY_ID   MAT_GEN_ID
----------- -----------
3069929     50035
3069929     50036

3069929     50042
3069929     50037
```

=============================================================================

=============================================================================
[SLURRY]

```
SLURRY_ID
-----------
3069928
```

[QUERY_V]

```
SLURRY_ID   MAT_GEN_ID
----------- -----------
3069928     50035
3069928     50036
```

=============================================================================

Requirement here is to implement a dynamic search which would provide a material IDs in the search criteria and the result would contain only those slurries which are having only those materials specified in the search criteria.

for example here if user provides the material ids i.e. 50035 & 50036 in the search criteria then it would result only the second slurry i.e. with id 3069928. The result should not include the first Slurry even though it contains the materials specified in the search criteria as it also contains two additional materials apart from the materials specified in the search criteria.

Any one if have any clue, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [pulling specific record(s) that match only a set of values across multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682470/pulling-specific-records-that-match-only-a-set-of-values-across-multiple-rows)

Comment: This is known as "relational division"

Answer (score 0):

Just group by the two columns and check if the number of rows equals the number of material IDs you are searching for.

```
SELECT 
slurry_id, mat_gen_id
FROM
material
WHERE mat_gen_id IN (50035, 50036)
GROUP BY slurry_id, mat_gen_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```